# Coding a reddit bot

Tags: java, scripting, bots

I want to create a reddit 'novelty' account bot to better my coding/scripting skills. Currently I just want to make a simple bot that searches new or rising links on reddit and looks at the comments in each thread. If the text matches some string of characters, the bot replies with a message.

I know this is a really general question, but I'm looking for tips on which scripting/programming language to use. I mainly have experience with Java and Selenium along with R and a little bit of batch. I am willing to learn a new language (i have a lot of free time). Also the goal of the bot isn't very difficult, so even if i had to learn a new language I don't think it would be all too difficult.

Comment: Try python and use [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v3.1.0/).

Comment: If you know Java, then Python won't be hard to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most reddit bots are made with something called [PRAW](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/praw). You use Python when creating something with PRAW. Python shouldn't be too hard to learn if you know Java.